# Why is my AspectJ Advice being executed twice?

Tags: spring, testng, aspectj

My Advice is executing correctly and preforming the correct action except that is executing twice.  I'd like for it to execute only once.  The method that is supposed to trigger the advice is only being executed once since the startTestSuite title is only printed once in the logs.  The Beans and context are being generated in a TestNG class.  I have tried running it with the @BeforeClass and @BeforeSuite tags on the initSpring() method with the same result.
Further context:
The objective of this is to get a timestamp of when the test suite is started and ends and get timestamps of when the individual tests start and end.  Eventually I will be capturing the stack trace for when a test fails so we can build of pattern of where our test automation has the most issues and allow us to focus our efforts on the more important areas of the automation that need to be fixed instead of fixing trivial things.

Log File

```
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.646-0800 test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: context object instantiated
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.647-0800 test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Shutdown hook registered
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.647-0800 test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Obtained a Instrumentation proxy
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.661-0800 instrumentation.dao.implement.TestSuiteDaoImpl.beforeTestSuite: ***************Running Advice: beforeTestSuite: startTestSuite
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.948-0800 instrumentation.dao.implement.TestSuiteDaoImpl.beforeTestSuite: ***************Running Advice: beforeTestSuite: startTestSuite
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.952-0800 test.ui.tests.InstrumentationImpl.startTestSuite: Going to print the title: startTestSuite
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.952-0800 test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ********************
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.952-0800 test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** startTestSuite **
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.953-0800 test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ********************
[INFO] 2013-02-11 17:56:07.953-0800 test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Called the Proxy
```

TestNG Class

```
public class BVT extends SeleniumTest {    
@BeforeSuite
        public void initSpring() {
            titleLog.testTitle("initSpring");
            context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-beans.xml"});
            Assert.assertNotNull(context, "Unable to load spring-beans.xml");
            logger.info("context object instantiated");
            context.registerShutdownHook();
            logger.info("Shutdown hook registered");
            instrument = (Instrumentation) context.getBean("InstrumentationProxy");
            Assert.assertNotNull(instrument, "Unable to create a Instrumentation Proxy");
            logger.info("Obtained a Instrumentation proxy");
            instrument.startTestSuite();
            logger.info("Called the Proxy");
        }
}
```

Interface for Proxy

```
public interface Instrumentation {
    public void startTestSuite();
}
```

Called Proxy Method

```
@Override
    public void startTestSuite() {
        logger.info("Going to print the title: startTestSuite");
        titleLog.testTitle("startTestSuite");   
    }
```

Advice

```
@Override
    @Before("execution(void test.ui.tests.InstrumentationImpl.startTestSuite())")
    public void beforeTestSuite(JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.info("***************Running Advice: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
        DateTimeHelper dth = new DateTimeHelper();
        TestSuite ts = new TestSuite();

        //Get the current time
        Timestamp start = dth.getCurrentSqlTimestamp();

        //Update the object with the starting time
        ts.setTestSuiteStart(start);

        //Commit to the database
        saveTestSuite(ts);  
    }
```

spring-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="instrumentation.dao.implement" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> 

    <bean id="basicDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:datasource.properties" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="testSuite" class="instrumentation.dao.implement.TestSuiteDaoImpl" autowire="constructor" />
    <bean id="Instrumentation" class="test.ui.tests.InstrumentationImpl" />
    <bean id="InstrumentationProxy" 
                 class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
        <property name="target" ref="Instrumentation" />
    </bean>
```

Update:
I changed my pointcut to this (Insturmentation vs InstrumentationImpl) and it fired four times.

```
 @Before("execution(void test.ui.tests.Instrumentation.startTestSuite())")
```

Here are the logs with jp.getTarget().toString() added.

```
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.258-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: context object instantiated
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.259-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Shutdown hook registered
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.270-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Obtained a Instrumentation proxy
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.276-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: *************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.276-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** afterTestSuite Advice Method startTestSuite **
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.276-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: *************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.276-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ***********************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.277-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.InstrumentationImpl@cb754f **
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.278-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ***********************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.573-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: *************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.575-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** afterTestSuite Advice Method startTestSuite **
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.575-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: *************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.576-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ***********************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.576-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.InstrumentationImpl@cb754f **
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.576-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ***********************************************************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.581-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ********************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.582-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ** startTestSuite **
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.582-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.helpers.TitleLogger.testTitle: ********************
[INFO] 2013-02-13 14:51:30.582-0800 amazon.omaha.test.ui.tests.BVT.initSpring: Called the Proxy
```

Comment: I have a question - Any reason why you are using a ProxyFactoryBean, you can directly use the InstrumentationImpl right?

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say what is going on here without more context, but my guess is that somehow your aspect is getting registered twice.

Comment: I added some more context.  Don't know if that will help.  Let me know what you would want to see to provide more context.

Comment: I'm not an expert in spring bean definitions, but what happens if you remove the <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/> line?

Comment: I commented out that line and I got the same results/behavior.

Comment: Hmmmm...your last comment rings a bell. Perhaps you are also advising the generated CGLib classes.  In your advice, try logging the target of the advice (I think jp.getTarget() should do the trick).  See if these are generated classes or not.